# SCP hangs before File Transfer begins

Tags: file-sharing, scp, file-transfer

I am trying to move a file from a virtual machine (Ubuntu 18.04) on my local system to a remote server using a very basic scp command. This issue is present only on one particular server, others work fine so it is not a generic thing.

```
scp <file name> <user>@<complete_hostname>:~/
```

But this command does not proceed beyond authentication which is successful.

```
SCP Log: (from local machine, Ubuntu 18.04)
==========
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: 
RSA SHA256:<key> /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 'HOSTNAME' ([10.6.26.145]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_IN
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -r -d -t ~/received/


Form another  remote server:
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/username/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
username@hostname's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = C
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = C
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t ~/
```

I do not have any privileged access on these machines , is there a way to find out what is going wrong? What  would I need to do the same?

Comment: is the server you are having issues with possibly loaded with high IO and/or CPU usage?

Hanging sometimes means only "non-instant" action, which can happen for a lot of reasons (HDD is busy, no CPU cycles left, bad connection itself, delays or timeouts between auth and connecting (think f.e. firewall)

Comment: Ask the sysadmin if sshd_config has UseDNS set to yes.  Verify your VM can resolve in DNS if so.

Comment: @DennisNolte thanks for directing to the Firewall, It was indeed the security software blocking it, The IT Team asked me to change the file permissions and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to  be a firewall blocking the transfer. Reason being the file permission on my default shell's **.*rc** file.

My default shell is csh, and the File permission were

```
-rwxr-s---
```

Changing these to

```
-rw-r-----
```

solved the issue.

Comment: It totally didn't solve my problem. I'm pretty sure I need to reinstall linux at this point :-/

Answer (score 2):

For me, the directory I was `scp`ing to did not exist.

I was trying to send the file to `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\AnotherDir\AnotherDir\`. Once I changed the target directory to the `C:\Users\MyUser\`, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers,

```
# This will use port 2222
scp -v -P 2222 ~/local_file.txt admin@remote:~/dest
```

but

```
# This will use default port 22 and ignore your 2222
scp -v ~/local_file.txt -P 2222 admin@remote:~/dest
```

so `scp` could seem to hang this way (wrong port). The `-v` flag is your friend.